# Workflow to trigger Javascript?

Tags: workflow, javascript, ribbon, custom

Is it possible to set up a workflow to trigger (for instance) a javascript function on a list item? I could see the possibilities here but don't have a specific example.

The option to set up custom actions in the ribbon is nice and I'm wondering if I could utilize these two ideas.

Comment: Workflows execute on the server out of process from the web process, JavaScripts in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

It is always good to think in possibilities and not technology

Be sure to keep an eye on:

- Microsoft Flow: https://flow.microsoft.com
- SharePoint Webhooks: https://dev.office.com/blogs/introducing-sharepoint-webhooks